# [Win10 Pro]Bitlocker suspended just after encryption

Tags: windows, encryption

I have a strange problem. I have TPM (with restrictions - backward compatibility it says, PC upgraded from 8.1 to 10 PRO) and I wanted to encrypt the C: drive. Everything went OK, after reboot encryption has started and finished with no problems, but after entering in the command prompt "manage-bde -status C:" it shows, that protection is OFF.

When I go to the bitlocker function options in the Control Panel I see "bitlocker for C: drive is suspended", I have no option to turn it back on or something, I can just turn off (decrypt drive) or backup the recovery keys. Nothing else.

Is there any way to turn the BitLocker on?

I have Secure Boot enabled and full support for BitLocker. My PC (tablet) is ASUS T200TA with CS_Mode disabled (I use it as a normal PC).

It's bizarre for me because disk is encrypted, but not protected (?) by this encryption. I'm confused a little, how does it work?

Comment: Well, the first, obvious question is what happens if you run `manage-bde -protectors -enable C:` to un-suspend BitLocker? Usually you could do this from the GUI, but it's certainly possible from an (admin) command line.

Comment: hello, thanks for answer. It says "key protectors are enabled for drive C:" (that's all). But still, if I check status, it seems like there's no effect. Protection stands "OFF".

Comment: Odd. Try suspending it (swap `-disable` for `-enable` in the command above) and see if that does anything, then try re-enabling and see if that helped. If not, turn off BL and start again.

Comment: When I set protectors to disabled, an opened lock with warining symbol appeared over C: drive icon (explorer.exe). After changing back to "enabled" it said what I told before, and protection is still OFF. I'll start again and I'll see if something changes.

Is it possible that bitlocker has got bugged?

Comment: Hypothetically possible, sure, but unlikely. Worst case, you might need to re-install Windows, but that really shouldn't be required. Do make sure the encryption process goes as smoothly as possible.

Comment: Okay, now the drive is encrypting again (muuuuch slower than normally, but still). After reboot (system test) something changed - system wasn't asking me for password like before (I was logged in automatically). I don't know if this is correct, but I didn't change anything with netplwiz and so on.

I'll give info when any further progress will occur.

Comment: Nothing changed (still the same problem), but now I'm starting to think that it's supposed to be like this. I've read, that drive is already encrypted (inaccessible for external systems), but Windows is not protecting the drive by password (while my account is password-protected, it is not needed).

So I'll give it a try. I'm downloading Hiren's Boot CD right now and I'll try to get into drive C: via GParted or Parted Magic, whatever (built-in filemanager).